# R on Amazon EC2 (RedHat/Centos instance)

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

To set up R & RStudio Server & Shiny (Server) on Amazon EC2 is straightforward, see https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/bigdata/post/Tx3IJSB6BMHWZE5/Running-R-on-AWS. This will set up a Amazon Linux instance (RedHat/CentOS).

When specifying the following details in "Step 3: Configure Instance Details" --> "Advanced  Details", R & RStudio are automatically installed:

```
#!/bin/bash
#install R
yum install -y R

#install RStudio-Server
wget https://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.903-x86_64.rpm
yum install -y --nogpgcheck rstudio-server-rhel-0.99.903-x86_64.rpm

#install shiny and shiny-server
R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
wget https://download3.rstudio.org/centos5.9/x86_64/shiny-server-1.4.2.786-rh5-x86_64.rpm
yum install -y --nogpgcheck shiny-server-1.4.2.786-rh5-x86_64.rpm 

#add user(s)
useradd username
echo username:password | chpasswd
```

However, the installed R version is outdated (i.e. R 3.2.5). **How, to change this command to ensure that the latest R version gets installed?**

Comment: Does it have to be RH/CentOS?

Comment: I don't see anything older than 0.99.903 on the download2.rstudio.org
Also this page: https://www.rstudio.com/products/rstudio/download-server/
shows that version downloaded via specified URL is the latest one.
Are you sure that your R is outdated?

Comment: I was wondering about RH/Centos because it is the default Amazon AMI and convenient because of pre-installed stuff like Java.

Comment: The R installation is outdated. R is installed through `yum install -y R`

Answer (score 0):

First log on as root in the terminal

```
 sudo /bin/bash
```

The remove the old installed version of R

```
apt-get remove r-base-core
```

Edit /etc/apt/sources.list with `nano /etc/apt/sources.list` and add the following:

```
deb http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu trusty/
```

In the terminal add the publick keys with:

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-key E084DAB9
gpg -a --export E084DAB9 | apt-key add -
```

At the end update and upgrade the package list

```
 apt-get update
 apt-get upgrade
```

Now you have to install the new version of R with:

```
 apt-get install r-base
```

If you want to update the package in your library you can run `update.packages` indicating the path to where your libraries are stored.

**[Update CentOS]** 
Have you tried to update the repository

```
sudo rpm -Uvh http:/www.nic.funet.fi.pub/mirrors/fedora.redhat.com/pub/epel/5/x86_64/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

And then `sudo yum installal R`?

Just like the previous part of the answer, if you have problem you need to remove all the installed component of R and then installed with the updated repo: `sudo yum remove`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just to be on the same page: Is your proposed solution really for Redhat/CentOS (and NOT Ubuntu)?

Comment: I've tried on a standard Linux AMI and worked, i thought that this could work with Red Hat too. At least you get the idea of the process.

Comment: Thanks. I was rather looking to avoid that and to specify the command above more precisely, thus the latest version is directly installed.What confuses me : Is when you write "I've tried on a standard Linux AMI" as `apt-get` is the Debian/Ubuntu package manager, the standard Linux AMI on Amazon is to my knowledge Red Hat/CentOS (both of which use `yum`).